# Java split string using delimiter IndexOutOfBoundException

Tags: java, string, delimiter

I was having some trouble when trying to split the string by delimiter. Some sample inputs are:

```
2@8:00AM
3
4@9:00AM@10:00AM
5@10:00AM@11:00AM@12:00PM
```

I wanted to split the string using delimiter `@`, limit it to two times only and assign to different variables. Here is my code:

```
String[] separated;
String day = null, text1 = null, text2 = null;
separated = objects.get(position).split("@");            
day = separated[0];
text1 = separated[1];
text2 = separated[2];
```

However, I am getting some `indexOutOfBoundException` as some of the string do not have two delimiter `@` and some of them exceeded two.

My desired output is for the first string, I assign the `2` to `day variable`, `8:00AM` to `text1 variable` and `""` to `text2 variable`. Then I perform some logic to display in UI. Then I will proceed to split the second string.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test to see how many parts are put into the array by testing the `length` of the array.

e.g.

```
if (separated.length > 2) {
  text2 = separated[2];
}
else {
   text2 = "";
}
```

Comment: Hey sorry but just a quick check, let's say I wanted to split with another delimiter, how can I achieve it? For instance, 2@8:00AM%user1. I wanted to split using delimiter @ and %. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, `split` uses regex, so have a play on regex101.com and see what works (maybe some things like `split("@|%")`